# Keep widget pinned when scrolling both ways

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need to keep the red colored widget pinned to the bottom or the top, based on which way user scrolls in the list.

The initial state of that screen would be the second image (pinned to the top).

Any ideas in how to make it?

[image: Sketch]